# How can I overlay lines in a transparent, inactive layer over my screen?

Tags: x11, kde

I'm attempting to line up some items on my screen, and it'd be useful to have a mostly-transparent guide as an overlay. Ideally, I would draw a vertical line that persists in the foreground, while not stealing focus from the window beneath.

I've tried the built-in mouse marks in KDE, and [ardesia](https://code.google.com/p/ardesia/), but both draw in freeform, and don't allow creating straight horizontal or vertical lines. ([Gromit-MPX](https://github.com/bk138/gromit-mpx) appears to be the same.)

### Usage example

I've navigating genomes with [igv](https://www.broadinstitute.org/igv/), and sometimes I need to work out which features line up. I'd like to be able to draw temporary vertical lines to see what lines up, for example in the following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just (temporarily) set a grid as your wallpaper?

Comment: But that would be the bottom-most layer, not the top-most.

Comment: And that would prevent you lining up items on your screen? Perhaps you could be more clear about what it is you want to achieve?

Comment: @jasonwryan Good point. I've edited.

Comment: Have you tried `kruler`?

Comment: @garethTheRed Brilliant! Works perfectly. Please write it as an answer and I'll accept. I should've known there was something k* that was appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The KDE application `KRuler` should fit the bill.

To start `KRuler`, choose `Graphics->KDE Screen Ruler` from your K menu.

The rotation buttons allow you to change its orientation in steps of 90 degrees, or you can click your middle mouse button (if you have one) to change it to a vertical ruler.